# Php mysql while loop fetching rows

Tags: php, mysql

I want to fetch the `Experience` row from the database, which will level up the players accordingly to their experience, that is, the level is equal to experience ÷ 100.

For example, if the player's experience is 100, then he's level 1.
If it's 200, then he's level 2.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "DB");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM playerdata ORDER BY Bank DESC LIMIT 9999");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $row['Unique_ID']; // ?
    echo "<br>";

    $xp = $row['Experience'];

    if ($xp == '1') {
        echo 'You\'re level one';
    }

    if ($xp == '2') {
        echo 'You\'re level 2';
    }
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I don't know how to handle the while statement with a while loop yet.

How can I calculate the level for all users?

Comment: Reformatted your code to appear in the code box without side scrolling. - well, not much anyhow.

Comment: @Fluffeh: it still seems to scroll horizontally for me though.

Comment: what is this `$row['Unique_ID'];` doing alone?and you said if exp is 100 then the level will be 1,but you are checking exp =1 then level is 1

Comment: `if($xp==100)
        {
            echo 'Your level one';
        }`. It should be 100 and not 1 as per your question

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate the level accordingly to the experience, then something like this could be the answer to your question:

```
<?php

// This simulates your database.
$players = [
    ['Unique_ID' => 1, 'Experience' => '100'],
    ['Unique_ID' => 2, 'Experience' => '150'],
    ['Unique_ID' => 3, 'Experience' => '200'],
    ['Unique_ID' => 4, 'Experience' => '299'],
    ['Unique_ID' => 5, 'Experience' => '320'],
];

foreach ($players as $player) {

    // Basically, you want to get the level by dividing the experience by 100,
    // then rounding it down with the function floor(). No need for another loop.
    $level = floor($player['Experience'] / 100);

    echo 'Player #', $player['Unique_ID'], ' is level ', $level, "\n";

}
```

This outputs:

> Player #1 is level 1
>
> Player #2 is level 1
>
> Player #3 is level 2
>
> Player #4 is level 2
>
> Player #5 is level 3

Now, if you want to *update* the level for all users, then I would suggest one of the following:

- Use a cron job that calculates the level of all users (using the method described above) and update the database.
- Update the users' level when their experience changes.